# Padronização de espaçamento de indentação de código

Tags: html

Utilizado Sublime Text para o front-end, já tive que abrir alguns códigos antigos e tive problema com indentação. Vi que era só modificar o tab size.

Gostaria de saber se há um padrão de Tab Size para a construção do HTML de um site. Atualmente utilizo Tab Size 4.

Comment: No caso, "tab-size" é o tamanho do "tab". Não é a mesma coisa de tamanho ou espaçamento de indentação, que pode ser feito também através de espaços.

Comment: É importante não deixar sua IDE escrever em ``soft tab``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem vários padrões.
O mais comum é a identação com 4 espaços.

Eu recomendo o [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Indentation) como padrão para HTML e CSS.

> **Indentation**
>
> Indent by 2 spaces at a time. Don’t use tabs or mix tabs and
>   spaces for indentation:

```
<ul>
  <li>Fantastic
  <li>Great
</ul>
.example {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: 2 espaços parece o ideal, realmente.

Comment: Pessoalmente eu não gosto, acho que fica tudo muito grudado. Sem um IDE de verdade fica até difícil analisar um HTML mal construído.

Comment: No final, vale o que o Time combinar e levar até o fim. Eu costumo fazer com que o controller entregue o HTML compactado, então a identação, somente importa para os desenvolvedores

Answer (score 3):

Depende MUITO do *coding standards* da aplicação (ou do layout como é seu caso) e ainda do programador.

Uns esquerdistas defendem o uso de TAB por ser de certa forma universal, mas este é contra-argumentado pelos de direita que defendem o uso de espaços (normalmente 4) pois TAB é suscetível ao aplicativo que o interprete como um "espaço grande". mas os espaços contra-contra-argumentados com o fato de que, programaticamente, um TAB ocupa menos espaço físico que 4 espaços comuns.

A maioria dos aplicativos definem um TAB como algo entre 2-3cm. Outros mais, outros menos.

O menos pior a se fazer é configurar o IDE do jeito que você está acostumado para pelo menos ter uma experiência visual confortável. Se o aplicativo não suportar, faça uma substituição regular global antes de começar e depois que terminar de um formato para outro.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta. Você sabe me dizer qual o padrão dos navegadores? Pois, quando visualizo, por exemplo, o HTML no Chrome, ele tem um espaçamento incomodo.

Comment: Não acho que os browsers interfiram nesse ponto. Se o código que originou o HTML tiver fracionado demais os elementos (comum em código espaguete que mistura elementos da linguagem servidor com *output*) resultando em muitas linhas em branco consecutivas, espaçamento despadronizado e etc. o browser mantém. Porém, existem algumas extensões de navegador que corrigem isso, como o HTMLTidy do Firefox

Comment: @BrunoAugusto , isso é muito comum em frameworks, aonde o output html é dinâmico.

Comment: @MarceloAymone Eu sei disso, mas eu penso assim, se o *framework* vai, direta ou indiretamente, bagunçar o *output* do HTML, porque não tentar corrigir? A questão da indentação poderia gerar um *overload* terrível para aplicação, mas as linhas em branco duplicadas se resolve com uma simples ER. E também tem o lado o programador que na hora em que está criando o *template* poderia muito bem usar mais ou menos espaços do que deveria pra que o *output* saísse bonitinho. Pelo menos eu sou neurótico a esse ponto. :P

Comment: Olha o source da Uol e você ficará triste. eheheh
Sobre as linhas em branco, acho inaceitáveis.
Sobre o espaçamento zerar, acho normal e não me incomodo muito com isto.